# Bootstrap Grid Reset Size

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

These buttons are set-up so when the page size is at `xs` (they stretch to the whole width of page)
But when it goes in to `col-sm` size or above, I would like it to remove the full width so it returns them to normal, without gridding.  I was thinking there should be something to reset the grid on larger sizes, but didn't find it. I tried using `*` or `#` instead of `0` but that didn't work. Any suggestions?  Here is the code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <button class="col-xs-12 col-sm-0">Start</button>
    <button class="col-xs-12 col-sm-0">Back</button>
    <button class="col-xs-12 col-sm-0">Next</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: I have done some searching and can't find a good way to do this. You might need to hide a div of buttons at one size and make the same set of buttons at a different size.

Comment: @JordanD I was thinking the same, but just checking (new to bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your question 100%, but here's my solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/Zfbk5/

You'll need to add some custom CSS, to revert the width to "Auto".

```
button.col-sm-0 {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I updated the bootstrap original css to include `-reset` on all sizes. Using your example i did this: `.col-sm-reset{margin-left:auto;width:auto;left:auto;right:auto;float:none;}` for each size and it works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to see other solutions that are more support with bootstrap but one would be to make 2 divs containing the same buttons, and just change which are showing depending on the viewports.

```
<--Only xs viewports -->
  <div class="row col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <button>Start</button>
    <button>Back</button>
    <button>Next</button>
 </div>
<--All but xs viewports -->
 <div class="row hidden-xs">
    <button>Start</button>
    <button>Back</button>
    <button>Next</button>
 </div>
```